# Adding an option group to a stacked layout in MS Access 2016?

Tags: ms-access, radio-button

All of the controls on my form are in one "stacked" Layout. I am trying to add two option buttons to the form and have them behave like radio buttons. However I can not get the control group (frame) to go in the layout.

Is there a way to add option buttons to a layout and still have them behave like they are part of a control group? Or is there a way to add a control group to a layout?

Answer (score 0):

I've never noticed that before, but it looks like option groups/controls don't work well in the Access layouts. [Here's another user with a similar problem that found a workaround](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/db3006b2-ec98-4e35-b37d-d0bb44cb053e/alignment-of-checkbox-within-layout-grid?forum=accessdev)

Not sure if this is a reasonable solution, but can't you use the stacked layout to get all of the other controls in place and then remove the stacked layout and manually place your option group?